# Resource entry is already defined

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-drawable

I'm trying to add a splash.png image but when I compile it says this:

```
Error:error: Resource entry splash is already defined.
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\splash.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
Error:error: Resource entry splash is already defined.
res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\splash.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
Error:error: Resource entry splash is already defined.
res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\splash.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\German\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-    crunch -I C:\Users\German\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-12\android.jar -M     C:\Users\German\AndroidStudioProjects\BASEUNODISCO\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S     C:\Users\German\AndroidStudioProjects\BASEUNODISCO\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\German\AndroidStudioProjects\BASEUNODISCO\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\German\AndroidStudioProjects\BASEUNODISCO\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\German\AndroidStudioProjects\BASEUNODISCO\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package disepro.baseunodisco -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\German\AndroidStudioProjects\BASEUNODISCO\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
1
Output:
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\splash.png:0: error: Resource entry splash is already defined.
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\splash.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\splash.png:0: error: Resource entry splash is already defined.
res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\splash.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\splash.png:0: error: Resource entry splash is already defined.
res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\splash.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
```

The thing is that I don't have any splash.jpg in my files!! 
I once put one splash.jpg but I 've already delete it

Please help! It's getting me nervous

Comment: make sure you actually deleted it. clean the build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you tried to clean your project?

menu -> project -> clean

Answer (score 7):

#### The problem is that you can´t have the same file name inside your `drawable` folder:

```
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\splash.png:0: error: Resource entry splash is already defined.
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\splash.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
```

must have only a `.png` or `.jpg` file

#### delete repeated files and clean your project: `Project` -> `Clean`

Comment: I don't have to files with the same name, I don't have any splash.jpg

Comment: check your output, try a clean!

Comment: I delete this file, clean the project, and return the file. All fine.

Answer (score 1):

In **Android Studio** you can get rid of this error message by doing,

Build->Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

I was also having that issue. But with me, deleting bin folder and then clean and build project solved the issue.
Actually duplicates files were in bin/res folder.